# Preserve state of a view controller from multiple source segues

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

**Scenario**

I have a mixed project of Objective-C and Swift with both a navigation controller and a tab bar controller. I have a view controller (the only controller that is written in Swift) that has segues to itself on the storyboard from both the navigation view controllers and also from the tab bar controller. The persistence of the view only needs to be valid while the app is open or in the background.

**Issue**

The problem I'm having is keeping that Swift view controllers state the same when it's accessed from either the navigation controller or the tab bar controller.

**Possible solution**

Would one possible solution be to remove the segue from the navigation stack and only keep it on the tab bar controller? If so, would this maintain the state of the view controller if I segue programmatically from the navigation stack to invoke the tab bar controller segue? Would I then be able to even pass data to that VC?

Comment: It sounds like you have multiple instances of some of your view controllers. This shouldn't be a problem as long as they are all sharing a single instance of your data model. If you are storing your data model in the view controller then you need to refactor your code

Comment: That is exactly what happens with the Swift VC. The VC gets reinstantiated and placed on the stack resulting in lots of memory usage.

Comment: I solved my problem by using an Unwind